# Customize Progress Report screen in testing? (DevOps)

Tags: testing, azure-devops, reporting

In the progress report in the testing module, the "Run %" includes things like "Paused", "Blocked" and "Not applicable".  Is there a way to fine tune the Progress Report screen to exclude those from what's counted as being run?

Additionally, is there a way to add custom test outcomes?